# Why is my Lagrange interpolation algorithm not working?

Tags: fortran, interpolation

For some reason it never interpolates, but it gives 0 as an answer. The code is:

```
  PROGRAM LAGRANGE
    REAL X(0:100), Y(0:100), INTERP
    REAL TEMP = 1.0
    REAL POLINOM = 0.0
    N=10
    OPEN(1,FILE="datos.txt")
    DO I=0,100 !We 'clean' the arrays: all positions are 0
       X(I)=0.0
       Y(I)=0.0
    END DO        
    DO I=0,10 !We read the data file and we save the info
       READ(1,*) X(I), Y(I)
    END DO
    CLOSE(1)

    WRITE(*,*) "Data table:"
    DO I=0,10
    WRITE(*,*) X(I), Y(I)
    END DO


    WRITE(*,*) "Which value of X do you want to interpolate?"
    READ(*,*) INTERP

    DO I=0,N
        DO J=0,N
            IF(J.NE.I) THEN !Condition: J and I can't be equal
                TEMP=TEMP*(INTERP-X(J))/(X(I)-X(J))
            ELSE IF(J==I) THEN
                TEMP=TEMP*1.0
            ELSE
            END IF
        END DO
        POLINOM=POLINOM+TEMP
    END DO

    WRITE(*,*) "Value: ",POLINOM

  STOP
  END PROGRAM
```

Where did I fail? I basically need to implement this:

[Lagrange interpolation method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39QP5.png)

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Always use `implicit none`! Doubly so when having a problem and quadruply so when presenting the code to others but use it for the sanity of your own mind.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the "symbol-concatenation" problem (explained in the other answer), it seems that `TEMP` needs to be reset to 1.0 for every `I` (to calculate the Lagrange polynomial for each grid point), plus we need to multiply it by the functional value on that point (`Y(I)`). After fixing these

```
PROGRAM LAGRANGE
    implicit none  !<-- always recommended
    REAL :: X(0:100), Y(0:100), INTERP, TEMP, POLINOM
    integer :: I, J, K, N

    N = 10
    X = 0.0
    Y = 0.0

    !! Test data (sin(x) over [0,2*pi]).
    DO I = 0, N
        X(I) = real(I) / real(N) * 3.14159 * 2.0
        Y(I) = sin( X(I) )
    END DO

    WRITE(*,*) "Data table:"
    DO I = 0, N
        WRITE(*,*) X(I), Y(I)
    END DO

    interp = 0.5   !! test value

    POLINOM = 0.0
    DO I = 0, N

        TEMP = 1.0   !<-- TEMP should be reset to 1.0 for every I
        DO J = 0, N
            IF( J /= I ) THEN
                TEMP = TEMP * (interp - X(J)) / (X(I) - X(J))
            END IF
        END DO
        TEMP = TEMP * Y(I)  !<-- also needs this

        POLINOM = POLINOM + TEMP
    END DO

    print *, "approx : ", POLINOM
    print *, "exact  : ", sin( interp )
end
```

we get a pretty good agreement between the approximate (= interpolated) and exact results:

```
 Data table:
   0.00000000       0.00000000    
  0.628318012      0.587784827    
   1.25663602      0.951056182    
   1.88495409      0.951056957    
   2.51327205      0.587786913    
   3.14159012       2.53518169E-06
   3.76990819     -0.587782800    
   4.39822626     -0.951055467    
   5.02654409     -0.951057792    
   5.65486193     -0.587789178    
   6.28318024      -5.07036339E-06
 approx :   0.479412317    
 exact  :   0.479425550
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider the (complete) program

```
      real x = 1.
      end
```

What does this do?

If this is free-form source then it is an invalid program.  If it is fixed-form source then it is a valid program.

In fixed-form source, spaces after column 6 largely have no effect.  The program above is exactly like

```
      realx=1.
      end
```

and we can see that we're just setting an implicitly declared real variable called `realx` to have value `1.`. Such a statement is an assignment statement, not a type declaration statement with initialization.

Preventing implicit typing, as in

```
      implicit none
      real x = 1.
      end
```

will show a problem.

In both free- and fixed-form source, initialization in a declaration statement requires `::`, like so:

```
      real :: x = 1.
      end
```

And: use `implicit none`.